# latex thorn sans serif symbol in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am studying theory at university, and the lecturer uses this symbol for elementary probability:
[image: elementary probability]

I want to use it in math mode, but the best suggestions I got from http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html was:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\TH
textmode
```

and

```
\usepackage{ tipa }
\textthorn
textmode
```

What i need is this symbol, sans serif, italic, in math mode.

How can i reach it?

Answer (score 4):

The [Comprehensive list](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) shows a bundle of different `\thorn` symbols, depending on various packages.

The table below gives an example of some of the commands.

There might be some warnings, especially for the `\itshape` fontshape, since this shape is not available for all fonts/symbols

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\newcommand{\mythorntable}[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1} \tabularnewline
fontenc & \TH~\th \tabularnewline
tipa & \textthorn \tabularnewline
tipx & \textthornvari~\textthornvarii~\textthornvariii~\textthornvariv \tabularnewline
wasysym & \thorn~\Thorn \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\huge
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\mythorntable{Normal font}
 &
\slshape
\mythorntable{Slanted}
\tabularnewline
& \tabularnewline
\sffamily
\mythorntable{Sans serif}
 &
 \itshape
 \mythorntable{Italic}
 \tabularnewline
 & \tabularnewline
 \begin{tabular}{ll}
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Math} \tabularnewline
   fontenc & $\text{\sffamily\itshape\TH~\th}$ \tabularnewline
   tipa & $\text{\sffamily\itshape\textthorn}$ \tabularnewline
   \tabularnewline
 \end{tabular} &

\end{tabular} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As you can see, `tipx` does not provide italic `\textthornvari` etc. variants

Answer (score 2):

Use sans serif italic! `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pTH}{\text{\normalfont\sffamily\itshape\TH\/}}
\newcommand{\pth}{\text{\normalfont\sffamily\itshape\th\/}}

\begin{document}
$a\pTH b\ne a\pth b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Old questions but I just wanted to add that the commands `\TH` and `\th` for Fontenc only works in text and not in math mode. The way I did was:

```
$ \text{\TH}_n $
```

This allowed me to use the Thorn symbol with a subscript.

[image: Thorn symbol with subscript]

Answer (score 0):

For use in pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\setstacktabbedgap{.5ex}
\setstackgap{L}{8pt}
\newcommand\prob{\mkern-1mu%
  \slantbox[.3]{\stackengine{0pt}{$\mathsf{p}$}{$\mathsf{l}$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}%
  \mkern1mu}
\begin{document}
$(\prob(x) = .3)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one needs it in the smaller math styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,scalerel}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\setstacktabbedgap{.5ex}
\setstackgap{L}{8pt}
\newcommand\prob{\ThisStyle{\mkern-1mu%
  \slantbox[.3]{\stackengine{0pt}{$\SavedStyle\mathsf{p}$}{$\SavedStyle\mathsf{l}$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}%
  \mkern1mu}}
\begin{document}
$(\prob(x) = .3)$

$\scriptstyle(\prob(x) = .3)$

$\scriptscriptstyle(\prob(x) = .3)$
\end{document}
```

[image]